# How to programmably select elements of a Word document and copy to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Is there a way to get some sort of collection of "paragraphs, images, headings1, headings2" and other "word elements" with a VBA function call. I was looking into this, I ran accros `ActiveDocument.fields`, but it doesn't seem to be it.

What I need to do is copy these elements, one by one, into an excel document, but I do not know how to access them in the first place. Is there any collection or what would be the syntax for accessing these. My idea is to make a loop and use it there, I could be going about this wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word:

- Hit Alt+F11 to get the VB editor.
- Hit F2 to get the Object Browser.
- Type "Document" into the search box and hit Enter.
- Click on the row that says "Word" under Library and "Document" under Class.

In the "Members of 'Document'" list you will see all sorts of goodies!  That includes things like `Document.Paragraphs` :) .  You can then search on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/) for details of how to use the listed fields.  Prepare for lots of searching and reading online!

Once you have found the fields you are interested in, you will be able to try some things.  Once you have code that almost works, but not quite, you will be ready to post detailed questions here asking for further help.  See the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more on that process.

Comment: Thank you for directions, this is what I was looking for. I can dabble around the code when I know the structure, but where to get the structure has gotten me completely blank.